# Можно ли в Laravel 5.4 с помощью отношений вывести название из другого столбца?

Tags: php, laravel

Приветствую!

Подскажите, возможно ли в Laravel 5.4 с помощью отношений (или каким-либо другим способом) получить (вывести) название по ID из другого столбца?

Например, есть две таблицы:

`[user]
| id | name  | country_id |
| 1  | Vasya | 2          |
| 2  | Petya | 1          |`

и

`[country]
| id | name   |
| 1  | USA    |
| 2  | Russia |`

Как можно получить (вывести) запросом (что-то вроде `JOIN`), например,

`Vasya, Russia
Petya, USA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно. Раз один пользователь может относиться к одной стране необходимо настроить связь 1 к 1. 
В модели пользователя (User к примеру)

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->hasOne(County::class, 'id', ''country_id);
}
```

потом получаете записи пользователей

```
$users = Users::all();
```

передаёте их в вид и там отоображаете через название связи(название метода)

```
foreach($users as $user)
{
    echo $user->name . $user->country->name
}
```

Естественно в виде используете не ^это а синтаксис blade

Подробнее https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/eloquent-relationships